# Pass and update php variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html-select

Is there a way I can pass the php option value variable $option_value['price'] into javascript as a string, then each time a different option is chosen, the javascript 'updates' the string with the new value. I have tried with onchange() but must be doing something wrong. I am sure my mistake is because php is server side and javascript is client side, but I have no idea how to get the two to act how I want.

```
<?php if ($options) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
    <span id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">

<select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" onchange="getIt(this)">
        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        <?php $option_value['price']; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
</span>
```

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getIt(elm) {
var val = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].text;
window.alert(val);
}
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getIt() {
var val = "<?php $option_value['price']; ?>";
window.alert(val);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `onchange` looks right to me: http://jsfiddle.net/NYJUm/. Where are you adding the `getIt` function?

Comment: at the bottom of the code. I am having problems because the php variable is in an array. I can understand `<option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>`, but I can't understand `<option><?php $arrayVariable ?></option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it. What you have to do are:

1. Analyze the code (notice that I use jquery from google's account. You will need to at some point install jquery on your web site and use this one instead of the google's one.
2. Build your `fruits` array so it looks like the one in the example.

I have prepared page that will show you this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/7uudp/

Below is what it contains. Notice that this example does not use your variables. You will need to use them the way you want/need. I have also defined `entry_fruit` to show you how to chose the default one to be selected. Hope it will help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

fruits = [{n:"apple",p:1},{"n":"strawbery",p:3}];
entry_fruit="strawbery";

function build_select(select,list,which)
{
    $.each( list, function(i,v){
         var selopt="" ;
         if ( v.n == which ) selopt="selected" ;
         $(select).append("<option "+selopt+" value="+i+">"+v.n+" - $"+v.p+"</option>");
     }) ;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    build_select($("select[name=fruits]"),fruits,entry_fruit);
     $("select[name=fruits]").change(function(){
         alert("Price is $" + fruits[$(this).val()].p);
     }) ;
})

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="fruits"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So my task now is to figure out a way to get my php code into fruits, right?

Comment: Yes. That would be something like ( I cannot format it ;(, so I put NL after each new line )

    fruits=[ NL
    <?php NL
    your code NL
    ?> NL
    ]; NL

Comment: Is this correct: `$option_value['product_option_value_id']` is the same as n. `$option_value['name']` is the same as apple/strawberry. and `$option_value['price']` is the same as p:1,2,....?

Comment: @Travis: That I cannot really know. You don't need to keep structure of object in the array. You can change fields 'n', 'p', and so on. In general you have there at least *four* types of data - id (`product_option_value_id`), price (`price`), and name (`name`). There is also `product_option_id which` is different thant `product_option_value_id`. They may be that each product, represented by `product_option_id` can have different values represented by `product_option_value_id`. Or you have a typo in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getIt() {
var val = "<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>";
window.alert(val);
}
</script>
```

Like so? Looks to me like you just forgot the "echo".

EDIT-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val = "<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>"; 
function getIt(elm) {
    val = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].text;
    window.alert(val);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Edited it above, try something like that?

Comment: This alerts $option_value['product_option_value_id']. .text grabs what is echoed. since option_value['price'] is not echoed, it doesn't do anything with that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Revoking my previous entry.

What you need to do is to add `selected` keyword to your `<option>` element when you match your `option_value['price']`

Now yuou need to arrange your data in a little bit different way.
In your javascript, prepare an array that will map `$option_value['product_option_value_id']` to `$option_value['price'];`. When you build your `<select>`, for each `$option_value['product_option_value_id']` check if its price matches the one that came in initially from php.

Your getIt will simply take the `<option value="___">` value, find it in that map, and show it to the user using the `alert()` window.

Comment: way past me. I am altering opencart code... so most of what you said is greek to me... anyway, it seems I need to start by trying to find a way to have an option selected to start with. I'll see what I can do then I'll be back for more. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out I am way over my head. Any help on how to start this?